# AFDownloadRequestOperation and ASIHTTPRequest not resuming Download

Tags: ios, networking, dropbox, afnetworking-2

I am stuck in Resuming Download. I am using `AFDownloadRequestOperation` to download the file from `Dropbox` public link. Everything(Downloading and Resuming) was going fine. But suddenly i don't know what happened that Downloading is working fine but on App Restart Resuming is not working and each time giving `"Request Timeout"`. While with link other then Dropbox(public link) Downloading and Resuming both are working fine. I have also tried same with `ASIHTTPRequest` and getting same behave. So What can the reason is there any problem with Dropbox public link? or is there any restriction with these library?

Please help i am much worried about my project's Progress. Project progress is stop due to this problem.

Here is my code

```
 __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:url.absoluteString.lastPathComponent];

operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request targetPath:path shouldResume:YES];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate.downloadQueue removeObject:url.absoluteString];
    [weakSelf checkDownloadQueueForMoreDownload];
    NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
[operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile) {

    if (totalBytesExpected != totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile &&( weakSelf.isDefaultProgressSet == NO)) {
        long long bytesHasWritten = totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile-totalBytesExpected;
        [weakSelf.delegate downloadedNumberOfBytes:((float)bytesHasWritten/
                                                    (float)totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile)
                                                    forAnnotaionView:annotView];
        weakSelf.isDefaultProgressSet = YES;
    }
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: bytesRead: %d", 1, bytesRead);
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesRead: %lld", 1, totalBytesRead);
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesExpected: %lld", 1, totalBytesExpected);
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesReadForFile: %lld", 1, totalBytesReadForFile);
    NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile: %lld", 1, totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile);
    float progress = ((float)totalBytesReadForFile/(float)totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile);
    [weakSelf.delegate downloadedNumberOfBytes:progress forAnnotaionView:annotView];
}];
[operation start];
```

On resuming always going to Failure block.

Comment: Did you try other link from dropbox folder? How does it look?

Comment: This is the link of file placed in Public folder of Dropbox. It is something like https://dl.dropbox.com/u/261778990/filename.mp4